# for next inside a do while loop - not fully functioning

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a do while-loop that works well, but when I try to add a for each-next loop inside it, it stops after only the first do while-loop.  I'm really not sure what I need to add/remove to get back to a functioning loop

rgData, rgHeader, and RowSum are ranges that are defined earlier in my code

```
Dim myCell As Range, c As Range, firstAddress As String
Const strFindMe As String = "Index"

    With rgData
        Set c = rgHeader.Find(what:=strFindMe, Lookat:=xlPart).Offset(1, 0)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    Dim ColIndex As Range
                        Set ColIndex = Range(c.Address, Cells(Range(c.Address).Offset(MktCt - 1, 0).Row, Range(c.Address).Column))
                            For Each myCell In ColIndex
                                myCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]<>"""",RC[-3]/R" & RowSum & "C[-3]*100,"""")"
                                myCell.NumberFormat = "0"
                            Next
                        Set ColIndex = Nothing
                        Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
```

the reason I'm attempting to write the code this way, is because the report I receive is already pivoted, and so there can be several "index" columns required for multiple demographic measures

currently this is working for the first "index" column, but isn't moving to the next "index" column.

Any ideas would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: When you `Set c = .FindNext(c)`, you're saying `Set c = rgData.FindNext(c)` because of your `With` statement. Based on your initial `rgHeader.Find`, shouldn't it be `rgHeader.FindNext(c)`?

Comment: Good eye: I tried changing it in 2 ways (with rgHeader at the top, v rgHeader.find), but both still gave the same results:  only the first "index" column is being calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first Find is against `rgHeader` but your `.FindNext` references `rgData` (via the With block)

To simplify the logic I would separate the Find from the processing:

```
Dim matches as Collection, m

Set matches = FindAll(rgHeader, strFindMe) 
For Each m in matches
    'process m
Next m
```

Separate function to perform the find:

```
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection

    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: I like this idea, it might take me a bit to fold this into my code and test it out.  I'll update on my progress shortly.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I worked your code in and worked like a charm!  Thanks so much!  I might re-work some of the earlier code to take advantage of the public function / collection concept to make a few other sections cleaner as well