# VBA: How to do a counter loop the amount of times = a formula answer?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to perform a task as many times as a word appears in a range. How do I make the counter loop = a countif answer?

I would do the do until empty activecell method but the amount of rows underneath my referenced could be any number. (I'm moving down a list)

```
 Dim TotalEmployees As Integer

 ' TotalEmployees = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range("B:B"), "" * employee * "")

 ' WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B:B"), "" * employee * "") = range("P9")


For counter = 1 To TotalEmployees

    Cells.Find(What:="Employee:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.paste

Next counter
```

The comment lines are my current tries. Neither work, usually get the mismatch error. My expected answer is the amount of times "Employee" shows up in Column B. I don't mind having the countif in VBA = the countif cell in excel, but can't get that either. (Thats the P9)

Comment: You can take the `Find()` out of the loop into its own function and loop over the found cells - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242233/for-next-inside-a-do-while-loop-not-fully-functioning/54242352#54242352

Comment: `TotalEmployees = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*employee*")`